# When a DIV comes into view add class

Tags: jquery, css, viewport, addclass

I'd like to add a class to an element, like a DIV but also on an img, h1, etc. when it comes into the viewport when a user scrolls.

How do I calculate whether or not my element is in the viewport or not?

In pseudo: If #swing has entered the viewport add classes 'animated bounceOutLeft' (play animation using CSS3). When animation is complete remove classes 'animated bounceOutLeft'.

I just don't know where to start other than I know the code to add the class I want:

```
$('#star').addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');
```

**PROGRESS EDIT**

Thanks to @Bibhas I'm trying to implement this [OnScreen plugin](http://benpickles.github.com/onScreen/), which I think i've done because Dev tools says the classnames are there but these classnames are css3 transitions they just aren't playing, what could be the problem??

```
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#star")                             // get all <h2>s
      .filter(":onScreen")              // get only <h2>s on screen
      .addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');
  }, 1000)                              // repeat every second
})
```

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: @egr103 Check the usage here - https://github.com/benpickles/onScreen. You need to put it inside `setInterval`.

Comment: @Bibhas Thanks. I've got the class names being added according to DevTools but my animations won't seem to play.  Any idea why this would be the case? Code/question updated.

Comment: @egr103 Your code is missing the interval parameter in `setInterval` function. Check the example again.

Comment: I tried it with the code in my question (just updated) and still it refuses to work...any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently someone wrote a little jQuery plugin for that. From his code -

```
function isOnScreena(elem) {
    var $window = $(window)
    var viewport_top = $window.scrollTop()
    var viewport_height = $window.height()
    var viewport_bottom = viewport_top + viewport_height
    var $elem = $(elem)
    var top = $elem.offset().top
    var height = $elem.height()
    var bottom = top + height

    return (top >= viewport_top && top < viewport_bottom) ||
           (bottom > viewport_top && bottom <= viewport_bottom) ||
           (height > viewport_height && top <= viewport_top && bottom >= viewport_bottom)
}
```

The source code is hardly 20 lines. You can read and learn. - https://github.com/benpickles/onScreen

Comment: This is better suited as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Because the OP asked for a coding solution - not a plugin. SO is for asking and answering coding questions. Look at the question the OP asked, "How do I...?"

Comment: I think you didn't check the link. The 22 lines of code there clearly answers OP's 'How do I...?' Would you like if I copy the code @benpickles wrote and paste here? Would that be considered as answer?

Comment: I did. Read my answer. I pointed to the code he wrote just as he wrote it. If that isn't answering and giving credit, I dont know what it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24843/discussion-between-jay-blanchard-and-bibhas)

Comment: Thanks for the plugin nudge. It looks like its a goer but cannot get my code to work. See updated question with progress edit

Comment: @Bibhas SO is about seeing the code, not linking to the code. Posters get corrected on this all of the time. SO wants to have the code in the answer in the event that the original site, such as the one you linked to, goes away for any reason.

Comment: Turns out this answer was correct. I was using Animate.css and a few transitions do not work. Odd but fixed nonetheless.

Comment: Jay Blanchard is being a pedant here. It's not up to him to tell people what SO is about. One thing SO is not about is punishing people for trying to help. That is NOT how to build a community.

Answer (score 0):

The `getBoundingClientRect()` function may help here. [Here's a CodePen I did](http://codepen.io/ross-angus/pen/kXxVbV/):

```
$(window).on('load resize scroll',function(e){
    $('h2').each(function(index) {
        var h2Height = parseInt($(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().height);
        var viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
        // This will return true as soon as the heading crosses the bottom of the viewport
        if ($(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().top < (viewHeight - h2Height)) {
            $('h2').eq(index).addClass('added-class');
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit:** note that this assumes that the browser is running in Standards Mode.

**Edit2:** Following a suggestion from [@brandnewjames](https://www.reddit.com/user/brandnewjames), I've added some other event handlers into the `on()`, which will also account for actions outside of just scrolling.